# software with scheduler c#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a salesmanger for ebay and i need a basic concept how to schedule the jobs properly.

Let's say i have 2 jobs which should be performed at a specific time.

Sell item A at 15:00
Sell item B at 16:00

current time is 13:00

Currently i would do it like this:
1. sort all tasks by time
2. get time of the soonest task
3. Wait for the timedifference between the current time and the task (15:00-13:00 so for 2 hrs)

however this way is very unrealiable and bad coded (for example i start the program at 13:00 and it will wait for 2 hrs. But what if i decide to add another item for sale at 13:30 which should sell at 14:00)

I could avoid this problem by checking every second what is the next job, but I still doubt this is a good way to writte the code.

windows task scheduler is a really good example of what i need. (you set a job at a specific time and it gets executed then)

The programing language i plan to use is c#.

I am also pretty sure the question has been answered multiple times but unfortunaly i do not even know what to google for.

I hope someone could help me with some basic ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too board. There are many and many ways how you can solve this. It all depends on your application architecture. Example of what you need to know *(not full list of choices)*: You can use database, or file to set the list of jobs. The jobs will be edited in running application/another application. What should application do when the job was scheduled to 14:00 but application started 14:01, or 14:30?

Comment: You can use Quartz.NET library to schedule jobs with specific time using CRON expressions. Refer this: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html

Comment: FYI The task scheduler will not start the job **before** the given time, but it is **not guaranteed** to start it **exactly** at that given time. That will depend on the system load at that time

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the current implementation, you seems to be using Thread.Sleep to wait for 2 hours, right? If it is the case, your program is really bad coded.

Don’t sleep. Because within 2 hours your program cannot do anything, it cannot check if the job list is refreshed.

Use timers. Specifically, use System.Timers.Timer class.

Use a timer to check the job list, checking it once every second is OK. Use a longer interval like 2 or 5 seconds if you find performance issue in the timer.

For a job that needs to be done after 2 hours, just set a timer that fires after 2 hours and forget it, and remove the job from the list. If you find another job that is to be done 3 hours later, again you set another timer.